# Should I hash passwords when sending using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, hash, passwords

I'm really confused with hashing password when sending via ajax and sanitizing and validating the login in php.

Should I hash passwords before sending it via ajax?If I do what about sanitizing and validating hashed-password and storing another hash of ajax submitted hashed-password in database?
I know hashing a javascript hashed-password doesn't make any sense here.

Anyone can tell what is the best practice for sending passwords via ajax and sanitizing/validating in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common approach is to send the passwords as plain text to the server (making an AJAX call, in your case) and then in server make the hashing, before you hit the database either for creating a new user of checking if the inserted password is the correct one.

Comment: In addition to this, using an SSL certificate can help mitigate the potential security issues of sending plain text passwords and prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: @SlitCanvas that's for sure correct but that depends on the architecture used in his/her application. He/She may not use an SSL certificate or might use. Generally it is more secure, if he/she will use an SSL certificate.

Comment: @Chirstos Yeah I'm already using this method then it came in my mind that what if someone intercepts network and steals login deatils.I know I should use encrypted connection but I've read that passwords should be encrypted before sending via ajax.

Comment: @user3370495 In order you avoid the network interceptions, the most efficient way is to use an SSL certificate. If you use an SSL certificate you don't have to make any encryption, all the work for securing your communication between client and server is done via the SLL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using HTTPS on the wire, you might want to perform the hash on the client just to make it a bit harder for a hacker to retrieve the cleartext password. It's still best to use HTTPS of course.

There's also a cryptographic protocol called Secure Remote Password, which is intended to make it harder to dictionary attack the user's password.  It takes a bit of work to implement, though.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol